# HTML Horizontal Menu that Moves on Button Click

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a horizontal menu that shows all of the possible items given the browser size, the rest of the items are hidden (they do not wrap to the next line).  Then there is an arrow button on the far right side of the div, which when clicked, shows the next row of items.  How can I do this?  I'm not asking for anyone to write the code for me, I just need some direction.  Are there any examples online of this?  I don't want the arrow button to move the items slowly across the screen.  I need it to just "jump" to the next row.

For example if the list of items is made up of three, each li element is 100px long and the total page with is 200px, one of the elements will be hidden.  Once the button is clicked the first two items disappear and the last item displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, you can make the ul position:relative, then the li position: absolute, when clicked, change the positon of lis to show them.

Answer (score 1):

As Ji Guang said. There are many ways of doing this. All that matters is that how you would like to implement it, or better said how the rest of your project is implemented.

For the menu as Ji Guang said, you can create a horizontal style list (maybe use float left on li for that). The ul must be now declared as relative and fixed height or width with overflow hidden, or better off fix the height as much you want and set width relative to the page. For the arrow to go throw the rest of the rows what I guess you want is some type of carousel. Now there are plenty of good plugins available online for that. Or you can always have it done yourself. If you are planning to do it yourself then you need to follow Ji Guang advice. Put the menu ul inside another div and then play with ul's positioning.